# How can I automatically add watermark to video or image on nova-s3-multipart-upload package

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I am using https://github.com/ahmedkandel/nova-s3-multipart-upload Laravel Nova package for upload multiple files to S3 server.
How can I automatically add a watermark to any video or image uploaded?

Answer (score 0):

The package you're doesn't seem to have watermarking capabilities. For that purpose, you can use something like [Intervention Image](http://image.intervention.io/) library which has a nice API and is pretty easy to integrate and use with Laravel.